# why mvc3 saves to a local db when webconfig tells it otherwise

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I'm kinda new to all this MVC3 stuff, and in many terms programming. 
The concept is that i will show a list of datacontent which is at my remote db.
So as far as I can see my problem is that the data I'm trying to create/edit on my remote site, tries to access my local db(SQLExpress) to save it there, but of course without luck.
The connection as far as I can see is as it should be, but I will post it here to help solve the problem.
i tried turning off my local db, when trying to debug on my machine, and this caused this error:

> A network-related or instance-specific
>   error occurred while establishing a
>   connection to SQL Server. The server
>   was not found or was not accessible.
>   Verify that the instance name is
>   correct and that SQL Server is
>   configured to allow remote
>   connections. (provider: Shared Memory
>   Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a
>   connection to SQL Server)

which just tells me that it couldn't connect to my server which is kinda logic when i turned it off. Now, my webconfig looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
  For more information on how to configure your ASP.NET application, please visit
  http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=152368
  -->

<configuration>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="ApplicationServices"
         connectionString="data source=Provider=sqloledb;Data Source=ip;Initial Catalog=dbname;User Id=username;Password=password;"
         providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>

  <appSettings>
    <add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true"/>
    <add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true"/>
  </appSettings>

  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0">
      <assemblies>
        <add assembly="System.Web.Abstractions, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
        <add assembly="System.Web.Helpers, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
        <add assembly="System.Web.Routing, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
        <add assembly="System.Web.Mvc, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
        <add assembly="System.Web.WebPages, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
      </assemblies>
    </compilation>

    <authentication mode="Forms">
      <forms loginUrl="~/Account/LogOn" timeout="2880" />
    </authentication>

    <membership>
      <providers>
        <clear/>
        <add name="AspNetSqlMembershipProvider" type="System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider" connectionStringName="ApplicationServices"
             enablePasswordRetrieval="false" enablePasswordReset="true" requiresQuestionAndAnswer="false" requiresUniqueEmail="false"
             maxInvalidPasswordAttempts="5" minRequiredPasswordLength="6" minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="0" passwordAttemptWindow="10"
             applicationName="/" />
      </providers>
    </membership>

    <profile>
      <providers>
        <clear/>
        <add name="AspNetSqlProfileProvider" type="System.Web.Profile.SqlProfileProvider" connectionStringName="ApplicationServices" applicationName="/" />
      </providers>
    </profile>

    <roleManager enabled="false">
      <providers>
        <clear/>
        <add name="AspNetSqlRoleProvider" type="System.Web.Security.SqlRoleProvider" connectionStringName="ApplicationServices" applicationName="/" />
        <add name="AspNetWindowsTokenRoleProvider" type="System.Web.Security.WindowsTokenRoleProvider" applicationName="/" />
      </providers>
    </roleManager>

    <pages>
      <namespaces>
        <add namespace="System.Web.Helpers" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Ajax" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Html" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Routing" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.WebPages"/>
      </namespaces>
    </pages>
  </system.web>

  <system.webServer>
    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false"/>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
  </system.webServer>

  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Mvc" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-2.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
</configuration>
```

Now this is in my head correct. But I'm missing something but i have no clue of what.

also the error I get is when I try to load my customcontroller

```
 private DataContext db = new DataContext();

        //
        // GET: /CustomContent/

        public ViewResult Index()
        {
            return View(db.CustomContent.ToList());
        }
```

Comment: How do you know that it doesn't try to connect to remote server you specified? Btw. your connection string is not correct. Data source is specified twice and incorrectly.

Comment: @lad psst, you might want to make that an answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in the comment the connection string is not correct. It contains data source twice and in incorrect form.

Answer (score 0):

Try modifying your data connection. Your data source must include `"` to connect to your db.

> connectionString="data source="Provider=sqloledb;Data Source=ip;Initial Catalog=dbname;User Id=username;Password=password;""
>            providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />